# I am working with vlan, I have to write a server which used vlan interface to accept the packet?

Tags: linux, sockets, vlan

Hints about working with VLAN? I have to write a client-server program, where the client will send a packet through eth0 and the server will receive the packet on VLAN, and to send it to a concerned VLAN client should parse on which command line VLAN will receive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is nothing to do in the application to work with a VLAN. The VLAN is realized using a virtual network interface with its own IP address. From the perspective of the application this is not different from a real network interface with own IP address. The OS will take care about routing and encapsulation of packets and there is nothing to do from the application itself.

Comment: do I need to use an ethernet header, to send it successfully, and on the server do I need to bind the Interface.

Comment: @lazy_day: Again, there is nothing special you have to do in the application since it is all handled by the OS already.

Comment: if I have to pass vlanTag number, which sockaddr I should use for L2, does vlan packets comes under broadcast domain....

Comment: @Ink: Again and again - your don't have to pass the vlan tag. It will be added automatically based on the source and destination IP and which interface/IP is selected for routing by the OS.